# representation matrix of $A$-linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modules

Let $A$ be a ring.And $M$ be $A$-module.
Let representation matrix of $A$-linear map $φ:M→M$ be $N$.
$N$'s matrix entries are in $A$?
In other words, representation matrix of $A$-linear map is in $M(A)$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you taken linear algebra?  If you remember how to represent a linear transformation with a matrix, it's the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one large barrier to this being well defined. We must assume that such a module $M$ is free, i.e. it has a basis. If we do not assume this, then we cannot define matrices. If $A$ has an invariant basis number, so that every basis of $M$ has the same size, then any matrix representation of a linear map will have the same dimension. We will also assume that $M$ is finite-dimensional.

Assuming these conditions, one can define the matrix of a linear transformation in a way analogous to that of vector spaces. Taking $E=\{ e_1,\cdots, e_n\}$ to be a basis for $M$, and given that $\phi(e_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n N_{ij} e_i$ for $N_{ij}\in A$, then we can construct a matrix for our map exactly as we do for a vector space, the $ij$ entry of our $n\times n$ matrix is defined to be $N_{ij}$.

Comment: Then, every vector space(over characteristic 0 field )'s representation matrix can be in M(Z) because every vector space over ch 0 field can be seen as Z-module. Where am I missing?

Comment: Not necessarily, the basis of a vector space as a $\mathbb{Z} $ module (if it exists) is not generally the same as its basis as a vector space, since we need to be able to reach every element with linear combinations with integer coefficients, this likely requires an infinite basis.